# How to change month data value based on hemisphere in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am examining how a particular variable in biology is affected by differences in season. To quantatize the data, I used the DATEVALUE function in excel to convert the month to a number. However, I have data from both the northern and southern hemispheres, and want to set my equation up so that the month data from the southern hemisphere is staggered by 6 months. That is, January is counted as "1" if the data point from the northern hemisphere and "7" if it is from the south, and so on.

I am having trouble finding a way to enter the formula in excel that will take this into account. The code I have come up with so far is

=IF(A1="Northern",MONTH(DATEVALUE(B1&"1")),MONTH(DATEVALUE(B2&"7")))

Where A1 is the hemisphere and B1 is the month. Does anyone know how I could set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you are after:

```
=IF(A1="Northern",MONTH(EOMONTH(B1,0)),MONTH(EOMONTH(B1,6)))
```

You don't really need the first EOMonth there but I left it in in case you ever want to add months to the Northern Hemisphere